# Independant poisson random variable

Tags: probability, self-study

The number of people arriving at a post office in a day is a poisson random variable with parameter λ. If each person who enters the post office is male with probability p and female with probability 1-p, show that that the number of males arriving at a post office and number of females arriving at the post office in a day are independent poisson random variables with parameter λp and λ(1-p) respectively.

The proof to this in my book goes as follows

Let X denote the number of males arriving, Y number of females arriving

P ( X = a, y = b) = P ( X = a, Y = b | X + Y = a + b) P ( X + Y = a + b) + P ( X = a, Y = b | X + Y = a + b) P ( X + Y ≠ a + b)

Second part = 0 , So

(1) P ( X = a, y = b) = P ( X = a, Y = b | X + Y = a + b) P ( X + Y = a + b)

(2) P ( X + Y = a + b) = [e ^ (-λ)] [λ ^ (a+b)] / (a+b)! (the poisson probability)

(3) P ( X = a, Y = b | X + Y = a + b) = (a + b choose a) (p ^ a) ((1-p) ^ b)

and by finding P ( X = a, Y = b), P ( X = a) and P ( Y = b) the book establishes independence.

I don't seem to get why they would be independent though. If I think of the poisson distribution as the limiting case of the binomial, and frame the problem as if its an experiment with n trials where a 3 sided die is thrown n times and I let n->infinity (male, female, no arrival) then P (X = a | Y =b) ≠ P (X = a)?

Comment: Please add the [self-study] tag, and write formulas with $\LaTeX$ notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of what information you are conditioning upon.

In one case, that of your binomial thought process, you know the total number of arrivals, so naturally the number of male arrivals and the number of female arrivals cannot be independent *given the number of total arrivals*.

In the other case, that of the problem, you don't know the total number of arrivals, just that they are distributed Poisson with mean $\lambda$.  Given this, the total number of male arrivals and the total number of female arrivals don't have to add to any given number, they only have to add to a Poisson random variate with mean $\lambda$.  This makes all the difference.  Although it is true that for any given observed value of the Poisson r.v. the numbers of male / female arrivals are not independent, that doesn't carry over to the case where you don't have a value, you only have a distribution of the value.

A simple thought experiment might help.  Consider rolling two dice independently, e.g., a friend rolls one and you roll the other.  Clearly the values showing are independent (well because  I said so, admittedly.)  However, if you subsequently find out that the total of the two values equals eight, the two values are no longer independent, because they have to add to eight.  However, to a third person who doesn't know that the two values add to eight, the two values are still independent, because he/she cannot condition upon the (to them unknown) sum.  So, the values are either independent or not depending upon what you know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply jbowman. So in the thought process where there are 3 possibilities - male, female, no arrival, it works out to be a multinomial distribution and the number of  male arrivals and female arrivals are not independent,but if I let the number of trials go to infinity while keeping λ  =n * ( p male + p female) fixed and consider the probabilities again I find that the number of male arrivals and female arrivals become independent. So, going from some fixed number of trials in the multinomial case ( thought process) to an infinite number in the poisson case creates independence?

Comment: No, not quite.  As long as you *know the number of trials* you don't have independence, it's the *not knowing the number of trials* and having the number of trials follow a Poisson distribution that gets you independence.  I see what you're trying to do, but as $n \to \infty$, the number of male and female arrivals remain not independent, due to the fact that $n_{male}+n_{female} = n$.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply jbowman. I think I've been thinking of the sample space this whole time as the various male/female combinations and the different arrival patterns to the post office where each elementary outcome is like ( male - 12.02 am, female 9.06523 am, female 11.5789 pm) e.t.c.  whereas If i understand it correctly the sample space should instead be ( if I change male/female arrivals to people who buy local stamps/foreign stamps) (local,local, foreign, foreign..) and the probability associated with some particular outcome  where k total stamps are bought

Comment: "a" of which are local and "b"  of which are foreign = P(total stamps  = k ) * P (  local stamps bought = a, foreign = b ), the first probability being just the poisson one with parameter λ and the second one being the binomial probability of "a" successes and "b" failures.  It doesn't seem intuitively obvious that the number of local and foreign stamps bought should be poisson or independent. Is there any intuition behind it?